# Simple product with downloadable sample

Tags: product, import, importexport, simple-product, downloadable

I import products into Magento with a csv file.
Actually, these products are reals books. And I would like to import a sample of the books (in pdf).

When I import the products, I define them as simple product. 
Is it possible with simple product to add a downloadable sample ? 
Or I have to put the product as downloadable product when I import it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these books are real (printed) books that you want to ship to the customers, I believe they should be uploaded as simple products (since they subject to shipping). If you want to add sample of a particular book as downloadable sample you can use an extension from Magento Connect (there are few extensions that offer products attachments).

Or you can add an Attribute with Input Type 'Text Area'. Make it Visible on Frontend.

And then in when importing product you can type attribute value as HTML code with link to PDF sample download.

```
< a href="/some/location/sample.pdf" target="_blank">Download Sample of this Book</a>
```

Add some CSS and you can have downloadable sample attached to particular product.